# What is the new version of csrf in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, csrf

I'm following a tutorial and getting a TypeError with this line:

```
c.update(csrf(request))
```

This is the full view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators import csrf

def index(request):
    c = {} #dictionary called c
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'login/index.html', c)
```

Am I doing an old version of something that has changed? Did I import csrf incorrectly? I'm running the newest version of Django.

Comment: Whats the full error you're getting?

Answer (score 3):

The TypeError is because you have imported the csrf decorator instead of the context processor. It should be.

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
```

However, you don't need to manually include the csrf token when you use the `render` shortcut. It automatically renders the template with a request context that includes the csrf token.

```
def index(request):
    c = {}  # dictionary called c
    return render(request, 'login/index.html', c)
```

The `render` shortcut was introduced in Django 1.3, so there has been no need to call `csrf(request)` in the view for years (even before Django 1.3 it was probably easier to use `render_to_response` with `RequestContext`). Unfortunately, [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/) remained in the docs up to Django 1.8, so it's a lot more common than it should be.